# Webpack race condition causing bundles to be missed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the following problem on my production server. Bundles are generated and loaded from tiems to times. Each time I refresh the page I get different results, there are three possible outcomes:

1. GET https://*****/static/bundles/auth-0e4207bad21fde30f817.js 404 (Not Found)
2. Everything loads
3. net::ERR_ABORTED error

Here is my production.config.js for webpack:

```
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var webpack = require('webpack');

config.output.publicPath = '/static/bundles/';

config.plugins = [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats-prod.json'}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
];

config.entry = {
    main: './static/js/main',
    auth: './static/js/auth',
    pathway: './static/js/pathway',
    report: './static/js/report',
    upload: './static/js/upload'
};

module.exports = config;
```

And my config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './static/js/main',
        './static/js/auth',
        './static/js/pathway',
        './static/js/report',
        './static/js/upload'
    ],
    entry: {
        main: './static/js/main',
        auth: './static/js/auth',
        pathway: './static/js/pathway',
        report: './static/js/report',
        upload: './static/js/upload'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/bundles/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this race condition?